# jQuery conflict on my website

Tags: javascript, jquery, conflict

I believe my website is having a jquery conflict problem. I'm running the Camera (jQuery slider) which uses jQuery v1.7.1, and the Simple Instagram Fancybox which uses jQuery 1.11.0.

I'm loading the Instagram script in a php include file that will load if coded into the page but it will cause my slider to not load.

```
(Camara Slider Javascripts)
<script type='text/javascript' src='camera/scripts/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='camera/scripts/jquery.mobile.customized.min.js'>       </script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='camera/scripts/jquery.easing.1.3.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='camera/scripts/camera.js'></script>


(Instagram/Fancybox Javascripts)
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox2/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/simpleInstagramFancybox.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/demo.js"></script>
```

If you wouldn't mind please write the code in full with all tags and let me know where exactly to put each script, I would appreciate it.

My website is http://www.deatherageproductions.com, please feel free to view the source and http://www.deatherageproductions.com/instagram.html is my instagram script that I'm trying to run as an include file on my main page with the slider.

Comment: what makes you believe there's a conflict? did you check the javascript console on your browser?

Comment: Thanks for the idea martinezjc.  I do think it's possible it could be something else.  The only reason I thought it could be a jQuery conflict was because one script would load if I coded out the other. I'm not much for debugging javascript, and I'm not sure what the console is telling me.

Comment: Are you good at Javascript debugging?

Comment: do you mean that both script are not working together in the same (HTML) file?

Answer (score 0):

you are including the jquery lib twice,

change it to this order

```
(Camara Slider Javascripts)
<script type='text/javascript' src='camera/scripts/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='camera/scripts/jquery.mobile.customized.min.js'>       </script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='camera/scripts/jquery.easing.1.3.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='camera/scripts/camera.js'></script>


(Instagram/Fancybox Javascripts)
<script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox2/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/simpleInstagramFancybox.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/demo.js"></script>
```

Comment: John, 
Thanks for the idea, but it did not work. I think the Instagram/Fancybox script has to use that version of jQuery.  I thought I would try your idea first before I try the noConflict just in case I could get by without running both jQuery scripts.

Answer (score 0):

If you require both versions use $.noConflict

```
<script>
    var jQuery_1_7_1 = $.noConflict(true);
</script>
```

Like so:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='camera/scripts/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='camera/scripts/jquery.mobile.customized.min.js'>       </script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='camera/scripts/jquery.easing.1.3.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='camera/scripts/camera.js'></script>
<script>
    var jQuery_1_7_1 = $.noConflict(true);
</script>


<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox2/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/simpleInstagramFancybox.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/demo.js"></script>
```

Everything above the $.noConflict line will use 1.7.1

Here's the [jQuery Docs on .noConflict](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/)

Also, per your comment, from your page, if this needs to use that first version of jquery, change it to this:

```
<script>
    var jQuery_1_7_1 = $.noConflict(true);
</script>

<script>
    jQuery_1_7_1(function(){
        jQuery_1_7_1('#camera_wrap_3').camera({
            height: '56%',
            pagination: false,
            thumbnails: true,
            imagePath: 'camera/images/'
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Ted,
This is exactly what I thought would do the trick, but I'm not having any luck. I've seen this online and it has to be the right way.  Would you mind viewing my source and seeing if there's something that stands out to you? Thanks for your help.

Comment: lol oops... try just changing the variable to var jQuery_171 from var jQuery_1-7-1. Its trying to do math with the '-'s. I edited my answer to reflect underscores instead of dashes--my mistake.

Comment: Still not having any luck. I think martinezjc makes a good point, when he says, "what makes you believe there's a conflict? did you check the javascript console on your browser?" I checked the Javascript console and get:
    Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token -
index.html:33 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery_1_7_1 is not defined index.html:33 (anonymous function)

Comment: change this 
    `var jQuery_1-7-1 = $.noConflict(true);` to this 
    `var jQuery_1_7_1 = $.noConflict(true);`

You've got to get the minus sign out of the variable name

Comment: Sorry, I updated my code late. It's still having issues.
The debugger says there are errors on these lines

    Line 15 - var jQuery_1_7_1 = $.noConflict(true)

    Line 32 - jQuery_1_7_1(function(){

Comment: Try change the `$.noConflict` to `jQuery.noConflict` If that doesn't work, reverse the order and put the new version first and old stuff last. Per the console, jQuery_1_7_1 is coming up undefined, which makes me think something's hinky with the first version of jQuery

Comment: Ted, we are getting somewhere!! The slider is loading but not the slides. I have the instagram feed showing as well. The javascript console seems to think the problem is now with jquery.easing.1.3.js, Any ideas?

Comment: Try changing `var jQuery_1_7_1 = $.noConflict(true);` to `var jQuery_1_7_1 = $.noConflict();`

Comment: That seemed to get rid of the slider, so I ended up switching it back. The slides are just not showing. Should I have a noConflict for the easing script as well?

    <script type='text/javascript' src='camera/scripts/jquery.easing.1.3.js'></script>

This seems to be where to problem is now.

Comment: try removing the 'swing' bit in that file.

Comment: Works!! You are a genius Ted! Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: Should it matter if I am still getting errors related to the jquery.easing file?

my debuger is showing 
    Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ]
jquery.min.js:4 Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a functionjquery.min.js:4 f.fx.stepjquery.min.js:4 hjquery.min.js:4 f.fx.customjquery.min.js:4 gjquery.min.js:2 f.extend.dequeuejquery.min.js:2 (anonymous function)

Comment: It seems that I thanked you a bit prematurely... lol the slider with slide is up but it's not going to the next slide and I have the same errors that I listed above.

Comment: Put the swing bit back, and add this to the beginning of the file, or where you're initializing it: `jQuery.easing.def = "string";`. See [docs](http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/)

Comment: I tried putting that right before 
jQuery.easing['jswing'] = jQuery.easing['swing'];
which is considered the top and it didn't work. I'm not sure where it's initializing it though. I appreciate your help.